# Postgres select work 3x time faster then function with that select

Tags: postgresql

I have a SELECT in Postgres:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (price) price, quantity, is_ask, final_update_id
                 FROM (SELECT *
                       FROM ((SELECT price, quantity, is_ask, book_depth.final_update_id
                              FROM order_depth
                                       LEFT JOIN book_depth ON book_depth_id = book_depth.id
                              WHERE book_depth_id IN (SELECT id
                                                      FROM book_depth
                                                      WHERE final_update_id > (SELECT last_update_id
                                                                               FROM order_book
                                                                               WHERE symbol_name = 'XRPRUB'
                                                                               ORDER BY last_update_id DESC
                                                                               LIMIT 1)
                                                        AND symbol_name = 'XRPRUB'))
                             UNION
                             (SELECT price, quantity, is_ask, order_book_id
                              FROM "order"
                              WHERE order_book_id = (SELECT id
                                                     FROM order_book
                                                     WHERE symbol_name = 'XRPRUB'
                                                     ORDER BY last_update_id DESC
                                                     LIMIT 1))
                             ORDER BY final_update_id DESC) AS t) AS t1
                 ORDER BY price, final_update_id DESC;
```

It works for about 20 seconds.
But when I create function with this select this function works for about 1 min 40 seconds. Can someone explain me is it normal or I make mistake somewhere?

Comment: Did you create a `language sql` function or `language plpgsql`. How exactly are you returning the result from the function?

Comment: From what I gather: The function should be `LANGUAGE SQL` and marked as `STABLE` when not altering the database. What did you do?

Comment: I'm using language plpgsql